# WordPress Breadcrumb Taxonomy Display

Tags: plugin-development, custom-taxonomy

I have a problem in breadcrumb on an taxonomy page like that use 
taxonomy=pwb-brand&tag_ID=289&post_type=product

In breadcrumb show Home > Brands > Name
However when you do to Name page the Brands breadcrumb in not clickable with not a href inside, only appears the name, the Home have a href inside.
Is possible to get the breadcrumb with a href link?

A page with slug brands is exist.

Any idea how maybe this make it work?

I update to be more clear.
I have create a page `taxonomy-pwb-brand.php`

`pwb-brand` is a taxonomy created for `product` custom post type

My theme is the woothemes storefront

Any help how to make the brands breadcrumb work with an a href= ?

Comment: We need to see your codes to be able to answer more accurately.

Comment: I use this plugin https://github.com/titodevera/perfect-woocommerce-brands/blob/master/classes/class-perfect-woocommerce-brands.php